# DNS entries for AWS Website and GoogleApps Mail

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, google-apps

I need some help sorting out my DNS entries. I have a domain, lets say it's somecompany.com 
Off this domain I have a website on AWS Cloudfront, which should be accessible via www.somecompany.com & somecompany.com 
I also have Google Apps setup for email, so users have addresses like user@somecompany.com

My problem is that although I can setup the Google Apps DNS entries and get mail sent to the right address. As soon as I also setup the entry for the website the mail stops being received by users@somecompany.com. I suspect some type of clash between the MX records and CNAME of somecompany.com but I'm not sure how to fix it.

DNS table is as follows...

```
somecompany.com     CNAME   xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
www.somecompany.com CNAME   somecompany.com
somecompany.com     MX  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
somecompany.com     MX  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
somecompany.com     MX  ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
somecompany.com     MX  ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
somecompany.com     MX  ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
somecompany.com     NS  ns1.openprovider.nl
somecompany.com     NS  ns2.openprovider.be
somecompany.com     NS  ns3.openprovider.eu
somecompany.com     SOA ns1.openprovider.nl dns@openprovider.eu xxxxxxxxxx
somecompany.com     TXT google-site-verification=xxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem, you can solve it using this accepted answer posted by Michael-sqlbot

https://serverfault.com/questions/709415/dns-entries-for-aws-website-and-googleapps-mail

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create www.somecompany.com as an "A" record and point it at the IP address of the web server.  Creating a CNAME is like creating an ALIAS between the two.

Comment: Unfortunately Cloudfront can't provide a static ip address for an A record, only a domain. So that's why I've got the CNAME.  Any other suggestions?